# Given array of elements, count number of subsequences of length 'k', which form a Geometric Progression with given ratio 'r'

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of integers, and a ratio 'r', find the number of subsequences of length 'k', where each subsequence forms a G.P. with ratio 'r'.

```
Example : arr = [2,4,6,8,12,16,24,48]. G.P. ratio('r') = 2. 'k' = 4           
Output : 2
Explanation : [2,4,8,16] and [6,12,24,48] are 2 subsequences which form G.P. with common ratio 2 and are of length 4.
```

I can write code when 'k' = 3, but am unable to solve this when length of G.P. can be anything.
I have some preliminary idea similar to when k = 3, that we can consider every element of the array as the base element and then look for elements in its left and right subarray and see if the total length of G.P. we can get is of length 'k'. But I am having difficulty of building upon this idea.

Comment: General Practitioner? What  have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I believe GP stands for [Geometric Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), going by the examples given.

Comment: Start by implementing the brute-force approach: for every element `x`in the array, search to its right for `x*r`, then `x*r^2`, all the way to `x*r^k`. Count all the chains where you get to `x*r^k`. Next, notice that you're doing a lot of work over and over again. Find a way to de-duplicate that effort.

Comment: Of course if you're allowed O(kn) extra storage there is a straightforward O(n) solution.

Comment: In your example, the integers are sorted and all different. Is it always the case ?

Comment: No, it is not necessary that the integers are sorted or different. The integers could be anything, in random order

Answer (score 1):

In Competitive Programing, this should be solved using DP.

Let describe the problem again:
In an array `a` of length `n`, how many subsequences of length `k` is a GP, with ratio `r` ?

Let's call `dp[len][i]` is the number of way, we created a GP of length `len`, ending at position `i`.

Base case: there's always exist a GP of length 1, ending at any position in array

Now make tabulation: a GP ending at position `i` and having length `len`, is created from a GP of length `len-1`, ending at any position `j` from `len-1` to `i-1`. These position `j` satisfy `a[j]*r = a[i]`

The number of GP having length `k`, is the number of GP having length `k`, ending at any position in array from `k` to `n`

In this code, the start position of array `a` is index 1:

```
int GP_length_k(const vector<int>& a, const int n, const int r, const int k){
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        dp[1][i] = 1;
    }

    for (int len = 2; len <= k; len++){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = len-1; j <= i-1; j++){
                if (a[j]*r == a[i]){
                    sum += dp[len-1][j];
                }
            }
            dp[len][i] = sum;
        }
    }

    int result = 0;
    up(i,k,n) result += dp[k][i];
    return result;
}
```

Now let's optimize this idea a little bit: Instead of finding number of GP ending at  `j` from `len-1` to `i-1` that `a[j]*r = a[i]`, we can use something like "prefix sum"

At each position `i`, number of GP can connect to this position can be stored as `found[a[i] / r]`, which is number of GP has ending value equal to `a[i] / r`. These GP is found from `len-1` to `i-1`

Caculating the `found[a[i]]` for the `dp[len][i+1]` is caculating such positions `j` satisfy above condition, which is disscused from the above code.

O(n^k) Implementation:

```
int GP_length_k(const vector<int>& a, const int n, const int r, const int k){
    unordered_map<int, int> found;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        dp[1][i] = 1;
    }

    for (int len = 2; len <= k; len++){
        found.clear();
        for (int i = len-1; i <= n; i++){
            if (a[i] % r == 0) dp[len][i] += found[a[i] / r];
            found[a[i]] += dp[len-1][i];
        }
    }

    int result = 0;
    up(i,k,n) result += dp[k][i];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that keeps track of several chains at once.
If you see a new number x:

- It is the start of a chain of length 1, starting at x;
- It continues chains that started at x/r.

We need a data structure that can track the last number seen and the length of the chain. I propose a mapping of (number, chain length) to number of chains.

In C++:

```cpp
int num_chains(const std::vector<int>& arr, int r, int k) {
  using chain = std::pair<int, int>;
  std::map<chain, int> chains;
  for (auto x : arr) {
    chains[{x, 1}] += 1;
    if (x % r == 0) {
      // Find all elements in the range {prev, 0 -- k-1}
      // and copy their chain counts to {x, 1 -- k}

      int prev = x / r;
      auto lower_it = chains.lower_bound({prev, 0});
      auto upper_it = chains.upper_bound({prev, k-1});
      while (lower_it != upper_it) {
        chains[{x, lower_it->first.second + 1}] += lower_it->second;
        lower_it++;
      }
    }
  }

  // Finally, count all chains of length k.
  int count = 0;
  for (auto [pair, len] : chains) {
    if (pair.second == k) count += len;
  }
  return count;
}
```